How to display the risk/return metrics from riskfolio plots
I am going through the riskfolio library.
I went through the process described in this tutorial.
Next, I want to display the Expected Arithmetic Return, Expected Risk, and Sharpe Ratio for all 50 portfolios that are plotted on this chart.
https://nbviewer.org/github/dcajasn/Riskfolio-Lib/blob/master/examples/Tutorial%201%20-%20Classic%20Mean%20Risk%20Optimization.ipynb
a plot using the sequence described in the tutorial
Please help me find a way to extract the risk-return metrics of the plotted data.
I have tried to print the data from already defined variables like 'frontier', 'mu', 'returns'.
None of them can display the final risk-return metrics plotted on the chart.
It's all data attributed to individual constituents, the shares inside 'assets' list.
I also tried to manually compute the risk-return metrics I want, but the final numbers look vastly different from what is calculated and plotted on a chart by this function.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
